# Check for .NET and Install in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-installer, setup-project

I'm trying to make an installer for a program with user input in a visual studio 2012 environment. How do I go about checking for .NET framework when all the options available seem to run .NET (i.e. VB.NET, C#, F#).

I started a program in VB.NET at the 2.0 framework:

```
For i = 0 To (versionArray.length -1)
    if versionArray(i) = Release then
       exit for
    end if
next i
```

Where `versionArray` is an array of the Registry entries in SOFTWARE for `.NET 4.5` and
`Release` is the current entry, if it exists.

This code works but, as I said, it's running on .NET.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if it solves your problem, whether it be my answer or someone else's.

Comment: I'm still trying things out. Give me time, I know its been a while since I posted.

Comment: I think its been plenty of time :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a .NET Application without .NET. You will need to develop your installer with some sort of setup utility. With WIX configured correctly in your .NET Project and a setup utility, you can create what's called a [CustomAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx) to further retrieve information at install time.

Note that the setup utility will be the one to detect if the .NET framework is installed and enabled on the system, if not it will proceed with installing it; This will need to be setup ahead of time in your setup tool of choice.

Refer to this site for lots of great Installer tools and tips: http://installsite.org/

Here is a nice guide on installing .NET framework programmatically via `WiX`:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

**Here are some free setup tools you can use:**

1. [WIX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) (Windows Installer XML toolset--lets developers
   create installers for Windows Installer, the Windows installation
   engine.)
2. [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) (Free version, very easy to use! Free version includes limited set of features)
3. [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php%E2%80%8E)
4. [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Open source Setup tool)
5. [Ghost Installer](http://www.ethalone.com/download.html) (Free version available)
6. [ClickTeam Install Creator](http://www.clickteam.com/install-creator-2) (Very Friendly, Free version available)
7. [CreateInstall Free](http://www.createinstall.com/download-free-trial.html)

Comment: I'd add that WiX makes it pretty easy to build a *bundle* which will contain your MSI to install your stuff and the .NET prerequisite (or a downloader for it).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are doing because there are no setup projects in VS 2012 for building MSI files. Maybe that means you are writing your own setup program? If you want to detect the .NET Frameworks I recommend looking at the code here, C++

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2013/10/17/10457758.aspx

Comment: I'm attempting to make an installer for a program that checks for .NET but doesn't run .NET since it needs to check for it. I want something that's backwards compatible to an XP OS. The issue is that I can't install anything from the net or disk, I can only script, code, and work with anything that is on a standard install of 7 SP1 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: There is a "setup and deployment" package for VS2012 that creates a package with installation shield,but no connection to network or any outside data makes that difficult. I might try to get that package, and if I do that would solve my issues.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten you can get the 3rd party InstallShield LE.